# A/B testing app features via Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, ab-testing

Is it possible to A/B test app features via Google Play Developer Console?
If not, what alternatives are there?

Comment: I ended up picking A/B, by modulo 2 of the absolute value of the hash of the device Android_ID. I using Google Analytics to report results for each.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I now of. Try Kii's A/B Testing (just released). They have an SDK for Android (among others). Not integrated with Google Play Developer console though (they have their own dev console) so I'm not sure if this is a valid alternative for you.

http://en.kii.com/optimize/ab-testing/

Just my 2 cents.
Best.