# A/B Testing for builds in Google Play

Tags: android, build, google-play, apk, ab-testing

Is there any way to upload two builds for A/B testing in the Google Play?

The only two options i see are alpha and beta testing, but that's not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Google Play's staged roll-out feature if you're happy testing with your production users.

Steps:

1. Release one version of your app (A) to 100% users
2. Release second version of your app (B) which has a greater version number than A to 50% users using staged roll-out feature of GP

You'll end up with 50% users on your latest update (B) and 50% on the previous version (A).

Comment: But the new users will get the latest version only right?

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible to do A/B tests of two builds in the Google Play Store.**

The only kind of A/B tests possible in the Google Play store is with the store content: Screenshots, texts, etcetera. For this kind of A/B test, see [the Google Support site](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6227309?hl=en).

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708261/a-b-testing-app-features-via-google-play-developer-console) can help you a bit further when you want to do in-app-based A/B testing.

Answer (score 0):

the good solution is to integrate an A/B testing SDK in your App so you can customize some variable and gather some statistics, and later you can have a vivid view about your KPI's.

Answer (score -3):

Why not installing two different versions of the same app on different devices for this kind of purpose?